# How to do integration tests for @RabbitListener / @RabbitHandler?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, integration-testing

I intend to write integration tests to check whether my listener/handlers work properly.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE with the according amqp dependency.

I have written a custom sender (publisher) and listener (receiver). When conducting the publishing test I am able to debug into my publisher but I am not able to debug into my receiver which I tried to annotate with `@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")` on method level and with `@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")` on class level in conjunction with `@RabbitHandler` on method level.

What do I have to prepare to run such integration tests successfully?

I have already googled a lot finding some suggestions using `RabbitListenerTestHarness` and so on but this never worked. For `RabbitListenerTestHarness` I always get the error that no such bean could be found.